# Why scrapy raise response content isn't text?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the classifieds that are present in the epaper. When I try to run my piece of code I'm getting the error:

> NotSupported: Response content isn't text.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from imagecrawl.items import ImagecrawlItem


class ImgspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "imgspider"
    start_urls = ['http://www.deccanheraldepaper.com/data/pp3-20190621_10/webepaper/photos/541862.png']

    def parse(self, response):
        link = response.css('div.flex_grid img::attr(srcset)').extract()
        urls = []
        for pairs in link:
            for each in pairs.split(','):
                urls.append(each[:-3].strip())

        for img_url in urls:
            yield ImagecrawlItem(image_urls=[img_url])
```

**items.py**

```
import scrapy


class ImagecrawlItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()

    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `start_urls` is image url:

```
start_urls = ['http://www.deccanheraldepaper.com/data/pp3-20190621_10/webepaper/photos/541862.png']
```

Remove it and add link to the page with image link.